# AChartEngine Custom Axis

Tags: android

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXwgG.png)

Hello, i have a trouble with bar chart, i must remove this sticks on X and Y axis above numbers but i don't know how to do this, here is my code for creating chart: `String[] monthDays = new String[lastDayOfMonth];

```
    // Create month days labels
    int[] x = new int[lastDayOfMonth];
    for (int i = 0; i < monthDays.length; i++) {
        monthDays[i] = "" + (i + 1);
        x[i] = i + 1;
    }

    // Create series
    XYSeries majorSeries = new XYSeries("Major");
    XYSeries middleSeries = new XYSeries("Middle");
    XYSeries minorSeries = new XYSeries("Minor");
    XYSeries restSeries = new XYSeries("Rest");

    // Add data to series
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        majorSeries.add(i, majorData[i]);
        middleSeries.add(i, middleData[i]);
        minorSeries.add(i, minorData[i]);
        restSeries.add(i, restData[i]);
    }

    // Create series data set
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset xyMultipleSeriesDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    // Add series to data set
    xyMultipleSeriesDataset.addSeries(restSeries);
    xyMultipleSeriesDataset.addSeries(minorSeries);
    xyMultipleSeriesDataset.addSeries(middleSeries);
    xyMultipleSeriesDataset.addSeries(majorSeries);

    // Create series render for major data set
    XYSeriesRenderer majorXySeriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    majorXySeriesRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#4797b4"));
    majorXySeriesRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    majorXySeriesRenderer.setLineWidth(2);

    // Create series render for middle data set
    XYSeriesRenderer middleXySeriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    middleXySeriesRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#4ec697"));
    middleXySeriesRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    middleXySeriesRenderer.setLineWidth(2);

    // Create series render for minor data set
    XYSeriesRenderer minorXySeriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    minorXySeriesRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#1fb1ba"));
    minorXySeriesRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    minorXySeriesRenderer.setLineWidth(2);

    // Create series render for rest data set
    XYSeriesRenderer restXySeriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    restXySeriesRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#c2c2c2"));
    restXySeriesRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    restXySeriesRenderer.setLineWidth(2);

    // Creating XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize chart
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    multiRenderer.setOrientation(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

    // Add labels to x
    for(int i = 0; i < monthDays.length; i++) {
        multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, monthDays[i]);
    }

    multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    multiRenderer.setYLabels(0);
    multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
    multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(24);
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
    multiRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[] {-0.75, 31, 0, 0});
    multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);
    multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
    multiRenderer.setShowGridY(false);
    multiRenderer.setShowGridX(false);
    multiRenderer.setFitLegend(true);
    multiRenderer.setShowAxes(false);
    multiRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    multiRenderer.setShowGrid(false);
    multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
    multiRenderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(false);
    multiRenderer.setAntialiasing(true);
    multiRenderer.setInScroll(true);
    multiRenderer.setLegendHeight(30);
    multiRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    multiRenderer.setTextTypeface("sans_serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
    multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(maxValue + (maxValue * 2 / 100));
    multiRenderer.addYTextLabel(0, currency + "0.0");
    if (maxValue == 0) {
        multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(500);
        multiRenderer.addYTextLabel(500, currency + maxValue);
    } else {
        multiRenderer.addYTextLabel(multiRenderer.getYAxisMax(), currency + maxValue);
    }
    multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(-0.5);
    multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(11);
    multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
    multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
    multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{30, 30, 30, 30});

    // Add all renders to multi render
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(restXySeriesRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(minorXySeriesRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(middleXySeriesRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(majorXySeriesRenderer);

    // Create array of chart types
    CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef[] types = new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef[]{
            new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef(BarChart.TYPE, 0),
            new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef(BarChart.TYPE, 1),
            new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef(BarChart.TYPE, 2),
            new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef(BarChart.TYPE, 3)};

    // Get view of chart
    GraphicalView graphicalView = ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(getContext(), xyMultipleSeriesDataset, multiRenderer, types);

    chart.removeAllViews();
    chart.addView(graphicalView);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved
To do this you can set labels color same as your background or transparent

```
multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.WHITE);
```

After this you have to create your own class that extends chart class witch you need

```
public class MyChart extends CombinedXYChart {

int color;

public MyChart(XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset, XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, XYCombinedChartDef[] chartDefinitions) {
    super(dataset, renderer, chartDefinitions);
}

@Override
protected void drawString(Canvas canvas, String text, float x, float y, Paint paint) {
    paint.setColor(color);
    super.drawString(canvas, text, x, y, paint);
}

public void setColor(int color) {
    this.color = color;
}}
```

And finally you have to use your own class to create graphicalView and place it in layout

```
MyChart myChart = new MyChart(xyMultipleSeriesDataset, multiRenderer, types);
myChart.setColor(Color.BLACK);
GraphicalView graphicalView = new GraphicalView(getContext(), myChart);
```

This steps will override method from AbstractChart class witch draws only text values in your chart, but sticks will remain same color as your background, so they would be invisible